# How can I make a click for Recycler View and scan with equals? - Java

Tags: java, android, listview, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener

Due to the fact that the ListView is not optimized enough, I decided that I would switch to the Recycler View. The first problem that hit me was this one.

My RecyclerView adapter:

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;

    // data is passed into the constructor
    MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<String> data) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mData = data;
    }

    // inflates the row layout from xml when needed
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_box, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    // binds the data to the TextView in each row
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String animal = mData.get(position);
        holder.myTextView.setText(animal);
    }

    // total number of rows
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }


    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView myTextView;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            myTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_adapter);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    // convenience method for getting data at click position
    String getItem(int id) {
        return mData.get(id);
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught
    void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }
```

Using ListView I could do like this:

```
ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.testL);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("hello")) {
                    TextView details = word_dialog.findViewById(R.id.word_edit_desc);
                    details.setText("hello");
                }
            }
        });
```

How can I achieve the same result, but only with the Recycle view?:

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {

    }
```

I will be very grateful if you can help me!

I want to be able to click on the recycler view items in MainActivity.java, I already did it, now I need to be able to do my own actions on each line sorted using equals

```
        ArrayList<String> animalNames = new ArrayList<>();
        animalNames.add("Dog");
        animalNames.add("Cow");
        animalNames.add("Camel");
        animalNames.add("Sheep");
        animalNames.add("Goat");

        // set up the RecyclerView
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.myList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this, animalNames);
        adapter.setClickListener(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

 if (somecode.equals("Dog")){
            soundPlay(MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.star));
        }
        if (somecode.equals("Camel")){
            soundPlay(MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.tick));
        }
```

Comment: It seems like you have already created onItemClick method in Interface for handing click event? then where you stuck?

Comment: share your activity or fragment code where you want to access onclick event?

Comment: @AdityaNandardhane This click works, but I want to add a click to each line how in  ListView so that it works fine with the Search view

Comment: @SuperMen I think the listener do everything you needs and has identical function as the ListView#setOnItemClickListener. I am not quite sure the question you are asking and I afraid this will lead to a XY problem. So may I as what is your need, in layman terms and treat me as a new guy.

Comment: You want the ViewHolder to be clicked, then what? or you already can do it by yourself but you don't like the onClick relies on a Adapter which associate to the RecyclerView. So you want to see whether this can be replaced as similar as the ListView did.

Comment: @AndroidNewbieA I want to be able to click on the recycler view items in MainActivity.java, I already did it, now I need to be able to do my own actions on each line sorted using equals

Comment: Is there an example, if first ViewHolder TextView is "dog", 2nd one is "cat", 3rd one is "mouse". What you expect to be seen after clicking on "dog"?

Comment: @AndroidNewbieA see my question now below

Answer (score 0):

**This is Inbuild Click event of Recyclerview and another way to use Interface**

```
 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v ->

        if (animal.equals("Your animal String"){
    //Your code
    }
);
```

if want to use interface then this is reference [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-implement-item-click-interface-in-android/)

Comment: How can I use it with click? I want to use this with click

Comment: Please check I have updated the code.

Comment: it needs to be done differently, it doesn't fit

Comment: look my question now below

Comment: if Your are adding data to list so way you are check that ??

Comment: I will do this in the future with the Search View, I explained everything, I need to somehow place in the Activit `if` and check words using `equals`

Comment: But I do not understand why you are checking.??

Comment: That's why I asked the question, because I don't know how to check

Comment: To give every word its action

Comment: which type of action??

Comment: Sound playback and so on, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Suppose you have Thousands of animals then you can not prefer to check thousands of if-else conditions I think you should manage this with your list that has a way to achieve this.

Comment: I took the words in the ListView from Txt, for the Recycler View example I added a couple of words like this

Answer (score 0):

You can define an interface in your adapter, like below

```
public interface ClickListener{
    void onClick();            
}
```

Implement in fragment or activity that your adapter at:

```
ClickListener listener = () ->{
    TextView details = word_dialog.findViewById(R.id.word_edit_desc);
    details.setText("hello");
}
```

then pass interface to adapter use constructor or setter, and you can use interface in your viewHolder when bind like below:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(()->{
   if (your_list.get(getAdapterPosition()).equals("hello")) {
       interface_var_name.onClick()             
   }
});
```